# How can I add attrs to image in the code given below

Tags: django

```
    widgets = {
        'img':forms.ImageInput(attrs={'class':'box'}), 
        'title':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'box'}), 
        'title':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'box'}),
        'title':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'box'}),
    }
```

'img':forms.ImageInput(attrs={'class':'box'}), **this line gives me error.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The widget for `ImageField` is `FileInput` not ImageInput, django has no widget called ImageInput...

#### Try this code

```
'img':forms.FileInput(attrs={'class': 'box'}),
```